# File Open Mechanism

Tags: file, button, combobox, pyside

I'm trying to create an application. The application gives the user 2 combo boxes. Combo Box 1 gives the first part of the file name the user wants, and Combo Box 2 gives the second part of the file name. E.g. Combo box 1 option 1 is 1 and Combo Box 2 option 1 is A; the selected file is 1_A.txt.
I have a load button which is to use the file name , and open a file with that name. If no file exists, the application opens a dialog saying "No Such File Exists"

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide.QtCore import*
from PySide.QtGui import*

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle('cleanlooks')

        #PushButtons
        load_button = QPushButton('Load',self)
        load_button.move(310,280)
        run_Button = QPushButton("Run", self)
        run_Button.move(10,340)
        stop_Button = QPushButton("Stop", self)
        stop_Button.move(245,340)

        #ComboBoxes
        #Option1
        o1 = QComboBox(self)
        l1 = QLabel(self)
        l1.setText('Option 1:')
        l1.setFixedSize(170, 20)
        l1.move(10,230)
        o1.move(200, 220)
        o1.setFixedSize(100, 40)
        o1.insertItem(0,'')
        o1.insertItem(1,'A')
        o1.insertItem(2,'B')
        o1.insertItem(3,'test')

        #Option2
        o2 = QComboBox(self)
        l2 = QLabel(self)
        l2.setText('Option 2:')
        l2.setFixedSize(200, 20)
        l2.move(10,290)
        o2.move(200,280)
        o2.setFixedSize(100, 40)
        o2.insertItem(0,'')
        o2.insertItem(1,'1')
        o2.insertItem(2,'2')
        o2.insertItem(3,'100')

        self.fileName = QLabel(self)
        self.fileName.setText("Select Options")

        o1.activated.connect(lambda: self.fileName.setText(o1.currentText() + '_' + o2.currentText() + '.txt'))
        o2.activated.connect(lambda: self.fileName.setText(o1.currentText() + '_' + o2.currentText() + '.txt'))
        load_button.clicked.connect(self.fileHandle)

    def fileHandle(self):
        file = QFile(str(self.fileName.text()))
        open(file, 'r')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Test11")
    window.resize(480, 640)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: invalid file: <PySide.QtCore.QFile object at 0x031382B0>` and I suspect this is because the string described in the file handle isn't being inserted in the QFile properly. Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

The Python `open()` function doesn't have any knowledge of objects of type `QFile`. I doubt you actually need to construct a `QFile` object though.

Instead, just open the file directly via `open(self.fileName.text(), 'r')`. Preferably, you would do:

```
with open(self.fileName.text(), 'r') as myfile:
    # do stuff with the file
```

unless you need to keep the file open for a long period of time

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution also.

```
 def fileHandle(self):
        string = str(self.filename.text())
        file = QFile()
        file.setFileName(string)
        file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        print(file.exists())
        line = file.readLine()
        print(line)
```

What this does is that it takes the string of the filename field. Creates the file object. Names the file object the string, and then opens the file. I have exists to check if the file is there, and after reading the test document i have, ti seemed to work as I wanted.

Thanks anyway @three_pineapples, but I'm going to use my solution :P